# Is there any tips tricks , techniques, configurations to improve rendering time of sifr3-r436 text?

Tags: sifr

Is there any tips tricks , techniques, configurations to improve rendering time of **sifr3-r436** text?

What is best practices to use **sifr3-r436** to get good performance and cross browser rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few tips:

- Load sIFR CSS & JavaScript first
- Minimize the Flash movie size by limiting the glyphs embedded in the movie
- Make sure to hide the HTML text to prevent an obvious replacement
- [Calculate ratios](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Ratio+Calculation) to improve load experience

Comment: Does this presentation help? <http://www.slideshare.net/novemberborn/web-typography-with-sifr-3-at-drupalcamp-copenhagen>

Comment: I only understood ur first tips "Load sIFR CSS & JavaScript first". I want to understand other 3 points

Comment: Ok i saw presentation it was good. but what is the benefir to add ration to font var=  , will we get any improvement in spedd if we add ratios ?